Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
I am fetching a list of products from an api using retrofit and displaying it in an activity using recycler view. Now when I click on a specific item it should open its details page where there are more details about the product. It's working fine for first 15 items but after that I get this error in my logcat and in the app it just throws me to the first screen which contains a button(view products).
Here is the code of activity containing recycler view:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ProductListActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ProductlistRecyclerviewBinding
    private val productViewModel: ProductListActivityViewModel by viewModels()
    private lateinit var productAdapter: ProductAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ProductlistRecyclerviewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        initRecyclerView()
        getProductsFromInternet()
        productViewModel.productList.observe(this){
            it.let {
                productAdapter.updateProducts(it)
            }
        }

        productViewModel.isLoading.observe(this) {
            binding.progressCircular.isVisible = it
        }

    }

    private fun getProductsFromInternet() {
        productViewModel.getProducts()
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        productAdapter = ProductAdapter(arrayListOf())
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = productAdapter
    }
}

Here is it's viewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class ProductListActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getProductUseCase: GetProductUseCase
): ViewModel() {
    val productList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Product>>()
    val isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

    fun getProducts(){
        isLoading.postValue(true)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val products = getProductUseCase.invoke()
            Log.d("ProductListActivity", "Fetched products: $products")
            if (products != null){
                productList.postValue(products)
                isLoading.postValue(false)
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is its adapter:
class ProductAdapter(private val productList: ArrayList<Product>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ProductViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.productlist_item,parent,false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentProduct = productList[position]
        holder.render(currentProduct, holder.itemView.context)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            goToProduct(
                currentProduct, holder.itemView.context
            )
        }
    }

    private fun goToProduct(product: Product, context: Context) {
        val intent = Intent(context, ProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("product",product)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
    fun updateProducts(newProducts: ArrayList<Product>) {
        productList.clear()
        productList.addAll(newProducts)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}

and it's viewHolder:
class ProductViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val binding = ProductlistItemBinding.bind(view)

    fun render(product: Product, context: Context) {
        Glide.with(context).load(product.thumbnail).into(binding.imageView)
        binding.idTextView.text = "Product ${product.id}"
        binding.titleTextView.text = "${product.title}"
    }

}

This is the code of details screen where I am receiving the particular product:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityProductDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val product = intent.getParcelableExtra<Product>("product")


Not sure.  I suspect it has something to do with you use of "this".   I think you are binding to the saved instance instead of the current instance.  You should be binding after the update.

You should not implement it like that. you can try my following methods one by one.

At onBindViewHolder
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentProduct = productList[position]
    holder.render(currentProduct, holder.itemView.context)
    holder.absoluteAdapterPosition.setOnClickListener {
    goToProduct(
        currentProduct, holder.itemView.context
    )
}}



Or
holder.bindingAdapterPosition.setOnClickListner {  }

Also you should push running another Activity into the current activity instead of leaving it in recyclerview.
